# my code does should print the gap between prime numbers it does not work. "no errors"

Tags: java

im suppose to Ask from The user enters two integers, and inputs them through the console
The first is n, and the second is m. Print all the prime numbers up to n that are in between
The difference is exactly m.

---

this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EX1_A {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the the limit if the prime number you want");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter the gab");
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int arr [] = new int [n];
        int c= 0;// c is arr.length 
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            j++;
            if(Prime(i))
            {
                arr[j]=i;
                c++;
            }
        }
        
        int k = c;
        while(k>0)
        {
            for( int j = 0; j<k;j++)
            {

                if(arr[k]-arr[j]==m)
                {
                    System.out.println("the prime numbers with the gap " +m+ " is: {"+arr[k]+","+arr[j]+"}");

                }
            }
            k--;
        }
    }
    public static boolean Prime(int number)
    {
        for(int i=2; i<number; i++)
        {
            if(number%i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give some examples? sample input and output?

Comment: `arr[j] = i;` should be `arr[c] = i;`. I'm not sure what the point of `j` even is, just delete it.

Comment: `int j = 0; j++;` Your `j` is always `1`

Answer (score 0):

Change internal `if` where you find and save prime numbers.

```
int c = 0;// c is arr.length
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    if (Prime(i)) {
        arr[c] = i;
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you man i appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

This version works:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the the limit if the prime number you want");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter the gab");
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int arr [] = new int [n];
        int c= 0;// c is arr.length
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {

            if(Prime(i))
            {
                arr[c]=i;
                c++;
            }
        }

        int k = c;
        while(k>0)
        {
            for( int j = 0; j<k;j++)
            {

                if(arr[k]-arr[j]==m)
                {
                    System.out.println("the prime numbers with the gap " +m+ " is: {"+arr[k]+","+arr[j]+"}");

                }
            }
            k--;
        }
    }
    public static boolean Prime(int number)
    {
        for(int i=2; i<number; i++)
        {
            if(number%i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Great code answer, explain the difference to him outside of the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).